# display image of the clicked button in a new window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a grid-view containing an Image, name(string) and reference(string), the image is sized as 50x50 and contained in a button, so i want every time the user click on the image"button" the image is displayed in new window.

this is how i proceed

XAML code for the grid-view :

```
<Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
      <ListView Name="ListView">
          <ListView.View>
              <GridView>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="Image" Width="120">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 <Button Content="{Binding Image}" Click="ImageButtonClicked"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                   </GridViewColumn>
                  <GridViewColumn Header="reference" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Reference}"></GridViewColumn>
                  <GridViewColumn Header="name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"></GridViewColumn>
             </GridView>
         </ListView.View>
      </ListView>    

</Grid>
```

the button clicked event:

```
private void ImageButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        ImageWindow imageWindow = new ImageWindow();
        Button btn = args.OriginalSource as Button;

        Image img = (Image) btn.Content;
        imageWindow.ImageToDisplay = img;
        imageWindow.Show();

    }
```

the window that will display the image:

```
public partial class ImageWindow : Window
{
    public Image ImageToDisplay { get; set; }

    public ImageWindow()
    {

        Imagee.Source = ImageToDisplay.Source;
        InitializeComponent();
        ;
    }
}
```

when i  run this code, i get a 'System.NullReferenceException' ;Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

in Imagee.Souurce = ImageToDisplay.Source;

any help would be appreciated; thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that just instantiating an `Image` object without any parameters isn't just a null value?  I would simply inspect the value of `ImageToDisplay = new Image()`, this looks like it would not be assigning an actual image to that property.

Comment: My bad @ZachM. my code doesn't look something like this the ImageToDisplay = new Image(); is commented on my code ... i just forgot and uncommented it.

Comment: I'm seeing `Imagee.Source` you're sure that Image just isn't spelled wrong?

Comment: no it's correct. please @ZachM. i see that this question doesn't interesst no one can you please give me a way to do what i want to do different than this one ?

Comment: Unfortunately with what you have here I really cannot help much, however, I would suggest learning to write data to a log file to help you better understand what your code is doing at run time.  That will also help the community answer your questions quicker. I would check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663(v=vs.110).aspx Debugging will give you some more insight into what is happening during run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you are trying to it other way. execute `InitializeComponent()` before accessing any control in the window or user control. property values are not available in constructor as they are set after object construction.

```
public ImageWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //this line will always have error as ImageToDisplay is set after the constructor
    //Imagee.Source = ImageToDisplay.Source;
}
```

so create a new method for same and remove the property `ImageToDisplay` as not needed

eg

```
public SetImage(Image imageToDisplay)
{
    Imagee.Source = imageToDisplay.Source;
}
```

and to call like this

```
private void ImageButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    ImageWindow imageWindow = new ImageWindow();
    Button btn = args.OriginalSource as Button;

    imageWindow.SetImage(img);
    imageWindow.Show();
}
```

or if you just want to display image as whole in the new window you can leverage content property too

```
private void ImageButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    ImageWindow imageWindow = new ImageWindow();
    Button btn = args.OriginalSource as Button;

    imageWindow.Content = btn.Content;
    imageWindow.Show();
}
```

above code will work as long as there is a content set on the button, no matter what it is.